# pandas Grouping based on two variables

Tags: pandas, grouping, pandas-groupby

```
+---------+---------+-------+
| g_var_1 | g_var_2 | group |
+---------+---------+-------+
| A       | B       | 1     |
+---------+---------+-------+
| B       | A       | 1     |
+---------+---------+-------+
| C       | D       | 2     |
+---------+---------+-------+
| D       | C       | 2     |
+---------+---------+-------+
| E       | F       | 3     |
+---------+---------+-------+
| F       | E       | 3     |
+---------+---------+-------+
| G       | H       | 4     |
+---------+---------+-------+
| H       | G       | 4     |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

Using pandas:
I am trying to create a "group" variable based on "g_var_1" and "g_var_2". As you can see from the above ASCII table, the logic is that the same combinations of "g_var_1" and g_var_2" are grouped together. So observations with (g_var_1 == "A" and g_var_2 == "B") would be in the same group as observations with (g_var_1 == "B" and g_var_2 == "A").

The dataset that I am working with has more than a thousand rows, so doing this manually is not an optimal solution for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `sort` then use `ngroup` with `groupby`

```
l=['g_var_1','g_var_2']
pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[l],1),columns=l).groupby(l).ngroup().add(1)
Out[340]: 
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    4
7    4
dtype: int64
df['group']=pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[l],1),columns=l).groupby(l).ngroup().add(1)
```

.values

Answer (score 1):

Create a column with a combined `g_var` that stores a tuple including the two values.

In order to make them compare the same, keep the tuple sorted, so `"B", "A"` will also become `("A", "B")`.

You can use the `apply()` method, using a custom function, to achieve that result.

```
def make_tuple_var(row):
    var1 = row['g_var_1']
    var2 = row['g_var_2']
    if var1 > var2:
        # Swap them.
        var1, var2 = var2, var1
    return (var1, var2)
```

Then you can use it in:

```
df['g_var'] = df.apply(make_tuple_var, axis=1)
```

And finally you can `groupby('g_var')`, which will group all equivalent pairs together.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Neat idea, never thought to use tuples.